# Access from Java a Scala object that inherits from a generic Java base class

Tags: java, scala, generics, jvm, scala-java-interop

Sorry for the wordy title :) Here is the Scala object:

```
object TokenPosition extends java.lang.ThreadLocal[Int]
```

And here is the Java code that uses it:

```
TokenPosition$.MODULE$.set(position);
```

Eclipse gives me the following warning:

> Type safety: The method `set(Object)` belongs to the raw type `ThreadLocal`. References to generic type `ThreadLocal<T>` should be parameterized

What should I do? Or is this an inherent limitation of Generics and Java/Scala interop?

Comment: does the simpler `TokenPosition.set( position )` not work? does it still warn?

Comment: @SteveWaldman No, Java access to Scala object fields is a bit more complicated :)

Comment: i thought recent versions of Scala offered pretty forwarding methods, see "Forwarding Methods" https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/java.html here. But apparently that's only with companion objects, and probably not for inherited members. You could try adding a `class TokenPosition;` for the forwarding and specialize, `object TokenPosition extends java.lang.ThreadLocal[Int] { def set( i : Int ) : Unit = super.set(i); }`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `Int` to `Integer`, `Int` is like Java's `int`, and `Integer` is a wrapper, so it should help.